# Issue in Robot Framework while selecting frame and unselecting frame

Tags: robotframework

I have written the following scripts to select a frame and which works and navigates to a destination:

Variables file:

Comment: Did you try the keyword "select window" to unselect the frame?

Answer (score 1):

[Unselect Frame](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Unselect%20Frame) does not require any parameter

You could select a frame and then Unselect as following

```
Select Frame   locator
do something within the frame
.............................
.............................
Unselect Frame
```